# why saving the news record in typo3 7.6?

Tags: timeout, typo3

timeout saving news record in typo3 7.6 in addition to saving only part of the news content, the BE is very slow and also the association to tags is practically blocked, while the FE works regularly

Comment: How high is the memory max for PHP? Is there logging settings that make logging use memory alot? And is caching on?

Comment: FE is able to use more caching mechanisms than BE. Writing data like in the BE is impossible to be cached. So maybe, your resources don't meet your requirements... Could also be too many connections/access to the same database tables, so it's quite impossible to lock a table for writing.

Comment: In which context do you work (Development/Production)? Please describe your hosting environment. What other extensions are installed. Are there extensions installed which hook into the the Datahandler save process?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.